# Where would you generally find links for the src attribute of a JSONP call (for any random site)?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

Assuming the website you'd like to get data from doesn't have an API, where would you go on that site to find its data in JSON format (and if it doesn't have it in JSON format, is there a way to create a JSON with the data you'd like to retrieve)? 
For example, if I wanted to get, let's say, a body of text from another webpage or a video whose address is embedded in its source code, using a JSONP request to get a JSON file with the text as a string or the address as a string, is it at all possible (using pure JavaScript)?

Comment: No. You need to have a server side service for crawling a website.

Comment: could try Yahoo YQL.

Comment: If they don't have a publicly documented API, they might have a private API (use your devtools). If they don't have that either, you can use their search for "downloads" or "data dumps" or something, but you'll unlikely find anything. If that fails as well, you have to scrape the data yourself.

Comment: …and of course, whether any of this supports JSONP is an entirely different question.

Comment: if a site doesn't have an API (no matter what format) then neither JSON or JSONp request to that site will be an option

Comment: I see, so a website needs to have an API in order to make a request to it to return data in the form of a JSON... Thanks!